# Non-static method App\Models\Post::projects() should not be called statically

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use query scopes in my projects but it gives above error.. Probably I'm doing a mistake somewhere but what is it ?

in model

```
public function projects($query) {
     return $query->where('category_id',13);
}
```

in route

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function ($slug) {
  $proje = \App\Models\Post::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
  $related_projects = \App\Models\Post::projects()->where('id','!=',$proje->id)
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->select('title', 'slug')->get();
  return view('frontend.projects.projects_single', compact('proje','related_projects'));
})->name('projects.single');
```

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function scopeProjects($query) {
     return $query->where('category_id',13);
}
```

Now you can call

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function ($slug) {
  $proje = \App\Models\Post::whereSlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
  $related_projects = \App\Models\Post::projects()->where('id','!=',$proje->id)
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->select('title', 'slug')->get();
  return view('frontend.projects.projects_single', compact('proje','related_projects'));
})->name('projects.single');
```

It will work as expected

You find more about local [scope()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes)